# Can I install a single 8gb module on my Asrock H55m-le motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I would like to know if i can install a single 8gb module on my motherboard Asrock h55m-le. Or do i need two single 4gb module ? 
In manual isn't specified if i can ... how to find an information like this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H55M-LE/?cat=Specifications) link from the ASrock website, the max supported RAM memory is 8GB.

```
Dual Channel DDR3 memory technology
- 2 x DDR3 DIMM slots
- Supports DDR3 2600+(OC)/2133(OC)/1866(OC)/1600/1333/1066 non-ECC, un-buffered memory
- Max. capacity of system memory: 8GB*
- Supports Intel® Extreme Memory Profile (XMP)

*Due to the operating system limitation, the actual memory size may be less than 4GB for the reservation for system usage under Windows® 32-bit OS. For Windows® 64-bit OS with 64-bit CPU, there is no such limitation.
```

Small note: these are the manufacturers specs, this does not necessary mean that adding more then 8GB **wont** work, but there is a chance it will work, though the manufacturer does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

In general:

Yes, you can. Current computers use a 64 bit memory bus and a regular DIMM is 64 bit wide.<sup>*1:</sup>
That means that it can run just fine with only a single DIMM.

Most systems are also dual channel, which means you can add memory in pair and then the memory controller can do smart things. In that case your computers speeds up by about 5% on average.

Note 1: When using a single DIMM you often have to put it in a very specific memory slot. E.g. if the board has slots  1a 2a 1b 2b then a single DIMM might need to go in 1a and the system might not POST if you place it elsewhere.<sup>*2:</sup>

Note 2: And the memory controller (usually on the CPU die these days) and the motherboard need to accept the DIMM. Which means it has to be the right type (buffered vs unbuffered, ECC vs plain,not larger than supported, and in the right voltage range).

Note 3: A max memory size might be mentioned. Usually this is not the max which is supported but the max which is tested. (and tested with meomory available at the time the manual was written. Larger modules tend to come out at later dates and may or may not work.

> How to find an information like this?

Generally you look on your motherboard manual. Either the paper or [the PDF version](ftp://europe.asrock.com/Manual/H55M-LE.pdf) which ships with the motherboard.<sup>*3:</sup> Or you look it up on-line.

The last can be done on [the motherboard manufacturers site](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H55M-LE/), or you can use one of the memory scanner which sites which sell RAM use. Their goal is to sell you compatible RAM (and not deal with returned units).

---

<sup>*1:</sup>: Ignoring ECCs DIMMs, which can be 72 bit wide but still provide 64 bits of useable data.

<sup>*2:</sup>: In the case of your specific motherboard: It only has two DIMM sockets.

<sup>*3:</sup>: See page 5 for memory specs